# when resize my photo, what should i use function among floor, round, ceil in Matlab?

Tags: image, matlab

when resize my photo, what should i use function among floor, round, ceil in Matlab?

myimg (256, 256)

when scalefactor is 0.8

256 * 0.8 = 204.8

and then, scaled size of myimg (204.8 , 204.8)

in this case, ceil(204.8) or floor(204.8) or round(204.8)

what should I do?

Comment: Depends on what you need. You may also use `imresize`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the previous commenter outlined it depends on what you need and the use case. Just for anyone looking for functional clarity:

1. `ceil()` : Returns the closest integer greater than the input value.
2. `round()`: Rounds the input to the closest integer (decimals greater than 0.5 round-up).
3. `floor()` : Returns the closest integer lesser than the input value.

Example:

`ceil(204.8)` → 205

`round(204.8)` → 205 and `round(204.2)` → 204

`floor(204.8)` → 204

Extension:

In this case, if your criteria required an image of at least 80% of the original I would use `ceil()`. If you require an image size of less than 80% of the original then `floor()` would best suit. In any other case where the scenario is flexible `round()` is a good option which will give the closest image resizing down to 80%.